# Double negation of an i-adjective

Tags: negation, i-adjectives

Does it exist as such, the double negation of an i-adjective, e.g.: おいしくなくない? I was told that I should use おいしくなく　は　ない instead. Is that right? Is it a rule? Would it depend on context which was a question like: Are the meals at that restaurant good? Or is it just the style of the person I talked to?

Of course, I could also use e.g. まずくない instead, but this is not the question here.

Comment: なくない? is sometimes used by the young as a tag-question.

Comment: @Yuuichi Tam - you mean like じゃない？

Comment: Yes, it's a slang. おいしくなくない? (It is not delicious, is it?)

Comment: @Yuuichi Tam - Don't you mean: She is cute, isn't she? With your translation just ない would be the tag-question and not なくない.

Comment: 彼女はかわいくない?(She is cute, isn't she?) 彼女はかわいくなくない?(She is not cute, is she?). However, adults rarely say the latter.

Comment: @Yuuichi Tam - thanks. "However, adults rarely say the latter." - Of course not ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The double negation of i-adjectives not only exists, but it is quite commonly used among us native speakers when expressing opinions **indirectly**.

Take 「おいしい」 ("tasty") for example, by far the most common double-negative form would be:

> 「おいしくなく**は**ない」

which means:

> "(the food) is okay/passable if not great"

That sounds fairly indirect, doesn't it?  The direct phrase would simply be 「まずい」 ("bad-tasting") or 「おいしくない」, which would often be considered too direct for the Japanese taste (pun intended).

We also say:

> 「おいしくなく**も**ない」

which means practically the same thing as 「おいしくなく**は**ない」.

I do not think that careful speakers would use 「おいしくなくない」 with no particle between the 「なく」 and 「ない」 to mean the same as the two above.  I would, however, not be surprised if I heard it in careless hurried speech.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may occasionally hear some ギャル say これ美味しくなくない？ when, for example, going to a highly reviewed restaurant, being somewhat disappointed by the food, then asking a friend for affirmation.

In normal speech, however, you will quite commonly hear people say double negatives with a particle in between.

> 美味しくなくはない。
> It doesn't taste bad.
>
> 忙しくなくはない。
> I wouldn't go so far as to say "not busy".

Answer (score 1):

From a grammatical point of view you can make double or triple or whatever-iple negations, though it's not something you'd throw in a normal conversation. As an example  from Ace Attorney:

```
-そんなことないよ。
-そんなことなくないッ！
-そんなことなくなくない！
-そんなことなくなくなくなくなく...
```

With exception of comic effect I hardly can imagine situation where you may need this.